# Magento 1.9.1.0 Order confirmation not send

Tags: php, email, magento, cron

I can't find a proper solution for sending order confirmation emails. Invoice emails are being send after a purchase is completed. The only problem is that the order confirmation fails to send.

In my database i can see that the order email is in the queue (core_email_queue). Processed_at is NULL.

I tested the cronjob with direct admin, and i am able to call a script that will send me a random email, so that is working.

Despite all that, i see that no heartbeat task is found with AOE_Scheduler.

Any ideas? It worked before and suddenly stopped working

Comment: More then likely there is no server cron configured.

Comment: Your hosting provider will be responsible for setting this up, unless you have access to crontab via ssh.  Do you have Sudo or root level access to the server ?  Newer versions of Magento have many more dependencies on proper cron configuration or if you changed hosts this is common as well.

Comment: @Rob i do not have root access to the server. So your guess is that the cron itself is not configured right? The weird thing is that if i call a php script on the root of the site with in the file a php mail script, i'm able to let the cron process this and i will receive the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. I changed the cronjob tasks in direct admin as suggested by the module.

The setup is as followed (keep in mind that AOE_Scheduler has to be installed:

* * * * * /bin/bash path_to_root_site/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * /bin/bash path_to_root_site/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default

Comment: When using the scheduler I typically do the same thing except I hit the stock cron.sh instead of the modules one.

Comment: @Rob tried that one as well, but with the stock one it didn't work. Just curiosity, but what could be a possible reason?